# JAVA ¿Cómo puedo saber a qué número está elevado mi variable?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa para hacer un cálculo en notación científica, pero no se como poner la potencia en el resultado. con el código actual mi FuerzaVerdadera daría un número enorme, quiero saber como conseguir el valor de fuerzaGrafica que debería quedar así 2,3x10^17.

````
       int exponenteCarga, exponenteCampo, exponenteVelocidad, exponenteFuerza;
       double fuerzaVerdadera, fuerzaGrafica;
       carga = Double.valueOf(txtCarga.getText());
       campo = Double.valueOf(txtCampo.getText());
       velocidad = Double.valueOf(txtVelocidad.getText());
       exponenteCarga = Integer.valueOf(txtExpoCarga.getText());
       exponenteCampo = Integer.valueOf(txtExpoCampo.getText());
       exponenteVelocidad = Integer.valueOf(txtExpoVelocidad.getText());
       
       fuerzaVerdadera = (carga * (Math.pow(10, exponenteCarga))) * (campo * (Math.pow(10, exponenteCampo))) * (velocidad * (Math.pow(10, exponenteVelocidad))); ```
````

Comment: Cuando dices "daría un número enorme", debo entender que no has probado el código???? Porque hasta donde recuerdo (puedo estar equivocado, hace años que no ve java), al imprimir double te pone automáticamente la notación científica, creo que para menores de 0.001 y mayores a 10 millones

Comment: @Yussef Eso hace. Aqui hay un [demo de ese comportamiento](https://paiza.io/projects/3tqBQRXCNl3WP8YHbWxi-w). La diferencia es que en lugar de usar la notacion `x10`, usa `E`.